# SoundCloud widget auto plays audio even it was configured not to auto play

Tags: soundcloud

My widget is set up like this:

```
<iframe width='100%' height='20' scrolling='no' frameborder='no' src='https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/540841578&amp;color==%23161616&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;inverse=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=false&amp;classic=true'></iframe><div id='soundcloud-embed' style='position:absolute; top:-70px; display:block; text-align:center; z-index:-1;'><a href='https://www.youtubevideoembed.com/faqs/'>How do I add a Youtube Video to Tumblr</a></div><div></div>
```

I don't want the auto play. But every time page loads, it does auto play.  How can I prevent the audio from autoplaying?

Answer (score 0):

You erroneously have two `auto_play=false` parameters in your URL.  Remove one:

```
<iframe width='100%' height='20' scrolling='no' frameborder='no' src='https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/540841578&amp;color==%23161616&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;inverse=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=false&amp;classic=true'></iframe>
```